# .NET 7 Rate Limiting - Rate limit by IP address

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, rate-limiting, .net-7.0

The title is pretty self explanatory. How do I rate limit the following limiter by IP address? In other words, each IP address is able to do 2 requests per 10 seconds.

```cs
app.UseRateLimiter(new RateLimiterOptions
    {
        OnRejected = (context, _) =>
        {
            if (context.Lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.RetryAfter =
                    ((int)retryAfter.TotalSeconds).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

                app.Logger.LogWarning("Rate limit exceeded, retry after {RetryAfter} seconds", retryAfter.TotalSeconds);
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests;

            return new ValueTask();
        }
    }
    // You're allowed 2 requests per 10 seconds.
    .AddFixedWindowLimiter("fixed",
        new FixedWindowRateLimiterOptions(2,
            window: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
            queueProcessingOrder: QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst,
            queueLimit: 0,
            autoReplenishment: true)));

app.MapControllers().RequireRateLimiting("fixed");
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @Neil, I want it to rate limit by IP address, not path.

Comment: You realise that lots of server load balancers won't actually transfer the originators actual IP address, right? It generally requires complex settings on the load balancer and things like X-FORWARDING-IP headers etc.

Comment: @Neil, this is not intended for distributed rate limiting anyway. You can't manage load balancers with it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/#comment-16082

Comment: If your server directly on the internet, or could there be ANY kind of server in front of it?  I'm thinking of, say Azure APIM, or other DMZ, it doesn't have to be a load balancer.  If you add some logging that outputs the HttpContext.UserHostAddress , does it output real IP addresses when run on the server (it will look like it's working fine if you run it locally).

Comment: @Neil, I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use HttpContext.UserHostAddress. I just found an official example https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs.Samples/blob/bae4c1836f9f0520ddad29f8364792cbb685d5b6/fundamentals/middleware/rate-limit/WebRateLimitAuth/Program.cs#L243, even tho I'm not quite sure how it works yet.

Comment: The problem is that UserHostAddress isn't always populated, hence why I suggest you do some logging first, otherwise the whole thing is a non-starter.

Comment: @Neil, `UserHostAddress` comes from HttpRequest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?view=netframework-4.8. Or what do you mean?

Comment: Yes it does, but many times, that value is simply not available because of a setting on one of the many servers between the client and YOUR code.  Don't waste your time implementing an IP rate limiter, simply to find out it doesn't work on your production server because that value is not available.  Believe me, I've been down that path.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with a partitioned rate limiter using IP as the partition https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/#comments

Comment: @EricJ. https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-web-api-rate-limiting/ and https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#ip-limits have achieved it using a weight http header. Perhaps, this implementation should be something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `PartitionedRateLimiter` is the way to go here:

```cs
PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpContext, string>(httpContext =>
    {
        httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-For", out StringValues forwardedFor);
        string? ipAddress = forwardedFor.FirstOrDefault() ?? httpContext.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress?.ToString();
        if (ipAddress == null) return RateLimitPartition.GetNoLimiter("none");

        return RateLimitPartition.GetTokenBucketLimiter(ipAddress, (key) =>
        {
            return new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions
            {
                TokenLimit = 100,
                ReplenishmentPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
                TokensPerPeriod = 25
            };
        });
    });
```

The tricky part is getting the IP address. As noted in the comments, when behind a reverse proxy or API gateway, *double check* the IP is forwarded in the correct header (in this example it is `X-Forwarded-For`). Else you will probably rate-limit your reverse proxy, which is not what you want. I use `nginx` as a reverse proxy, and the following configuration will always populate the `X-Forwarded-For` header to your app:

```
    # inside nginx reverse proxy config file
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

That being said, there are some issues with IP rate limiting. Some home-network providers will use NAT even with IPv4, as do some cellular network providers - so potential thousands of users using the same IPv4. Additionally, when you use IPv6, you might want to modify the code to use the whole /64 or even /48 subnet of the source host as a partion key.